# how to count all pointers and variables that using an dynamically allocated memory with malloc and new?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, reference-counting

if we override malloc and new  function we can track first created pointer . but how can i track and count other pointers and functions that using this allocated memory ? (q pointer in below code ) should i override Assignment operator and function call ? if yes how ? if the solution is to use reference counting with class and constructor and destructor i have to change all normal pointer definitions to class type ? i dont want change source code just want to include a library and count pointers to an allocated memory.

```
int ∗ p = (int∗)malloc(10 ∗ sizeof (int));  
int * q= p;
```

Comment: If you want to replace them, each compiler or compiler-and-platform will have different requirements.  For example, IBM AIX [malloc replacement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=subsystem-user-defined-malloc-replacement) differs greatly from GCC [malloc replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html).  Those malloc replacements will not be portable, if that's a relevant factor.

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::shared_ptr`? Why in your opinion it exists?

Comment: *if the solution is to use reference counting with class and constructor and destructor i have to change all normal pointer definitions to class type ?* -- Well, you have a choice -- either spend a little bit of time changing your pointers to `std::shared_ptr`, or spend a lot of time debugging possible memory corruption, double-frees, etc., with the uncertainty that you didn't address all the issues.  The notion of "counting all pointers", to me, should be considered a non-starter, as noted by the answer #Sam Varshavchik stated.

Comment: If you want to find memory leaks then use `valgrind` or similar memory checked.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. i want to implement a custom memory leak detector

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow yes i want to find memory leaks but with my own custom implemented memory leak detection tool

Comment: Great. Do you know how existing leak detectors work, and why they work this way?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.i studied most of free leak detectors in GitHub .most of them record new or malloc allocation information in a structure and when the free or delete function happen delete the related record from structure and in the end report all remain records as a leaked memory

Comment: So these don't need to know where in the program the pointer goes or how it travels there. They only record allocate-deallocate pairs and report unpaired allocations. What yours need to do differently?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. there are two types of memory leaks .one type is when an block of memory is inaccessible anymore and we can report those as leak .another type is when memory block is accessible ( there are live object and pointers to that )but don't need to that in future.all free available tools in git find first type of leaks ( like garbage callection tools)but is not enough and we should find second types of that.

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you are trying to do. Suppose a memory block is accessible from the root set. What is your reason to classify it as a leak? How do you know whether you will need it in the future? What does "need" mean?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. need means one of live object or pointers to that memory use in future. Its hard to know need of future but some articles published that predict that need with machine learning and other ways.if memory is accessible and we don't need it anymore is leak and should be free .

Answer (score 6):

C++ simply does not work this way, on a fundamental level. A pointer is a pointer, a memory address. There is no other baggage associated with it, that can be used to keep tabs on it in some form or fashion. A pointer to a class can be converted to a pointer to one of its sub-classes, and vice versa. You now get a completely different pointer. The original pointer may no longer exist, but other, related pointers can still remain.

A pointer to an array may have some math performed on it, resulting in a different pointer, then after more math the original pointer comes back.

A weird C++ program may write the raw pointer to a file, then get rid of this pointer, it no longer exists, then some time later read it back, and there you have it, the same pointer is back, and using it is still, very much, well-formed, and it still works.

Once an overridden `malloc` hands over a freshly-minted pointer it is no longer under its control, and has no further say in what happens to it, until `free` gets it. Hopefully it'll be the same pointer, and everything will be ok.

That's how C++'s pointers work. They are uncontrollable, and unmanageable. Higher-level programming languages like Java, C#, or Perl, keep track of all their pointers and manage them, this must be built into the core of the programming language itself, which is not the case for C++. C++ is not Java, C#, or any other language. In C++ it is the program's responsibility to keep track of them, and use them properly. C++ will not do that for you.

Comment: actually i think its possible with shared_pointers but i dont want change source code just want to include a library . there must be a way to count all pointers to an address memory without changing in source code .

Comment: No, there is no way to do it, authoritatively. C++ simply does not work this way, on a fundamental level.